# binding combobox to viewmodel, not showing selected item

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, combobox

I'm binding my silverlight combobox to a viewmodel. Unfortunately, after I select a item in the combobox, no selected item is shown in the combobox after the dropdown closes.

My Viewmodel has properties for DocumentTypes (for datasource, it has properties for DocumentTypeName, DocumentTypeID) and SelectedDocumentTypeID (for saving the selected item it) which I'm using.

Here is my code to bind the combobox, I do it in codebehind:

```
var dgViewModel = new DataGridViewModel();
Binding bDocTypes = new Binding() { Source = dgViewModel, Path = new PropertyPath("DocumentTypes"), Mode = BindingMode.OneWay };
Binding bDocTypeSelectedValue = new Binding() { Source = dgViewModel, Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedDocumentTypeID"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
this.DataContext = dgViewModel;
comDokumententyp.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, bDocTypes);
comDokumententyp.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, bDocTypeSelectedValue);
comDokumententyp.DisplayMemberPath = "DocumentTypeName";
comDokumententyp.SelectedValuePath = "DocumentTypeID";
```

What I'm missing or doing wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: SelectedDocumentTypeID property include correct set part?

Comment: SelectedDocumentTypeID property has only the Guid DocumentTypeId, not the item which is selected.

Comment: Did you try to raise `PropertyChanged` event for `dgViewModel.SelectedDocumentTypeID` after the binding was established? If that updates the selected item, then you probably can fix the initial selection by first setting `SelectedValuePath` (before binding `SelectedValueProperty`)

Comment: Thank you, but setting SelectedValuePath before binding SelectedValueProperty doesn't help. Still the same.